# Using S3 Bucket as Maven private repository with gradle

Tags: maven, gradle, amazon-s3

I am trying to use AWS S3 as a maven private repo..below is my build.gradle looks like-:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher
import com.amazonaws.auth.AWSCredentials;
import com.amazonaws.auth.profile.ProfileCredentialsProvider;

buildscript {

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.amazonaws:aws-java-sdk-core:1.11.5' 
}
}



plugins {
id "java"
id "idea"
id "eclipse" //run "./gradlew cleanEclipse eclipse" after importing to eclipse
id "maven-publish"
id "maven"
id 'base'
id 'signing'
id 'jacoco'
id "net.researchgate.release" version "2.4.1"
id "org.springframework.boot" version "1.5.2.RELEASE"
}

def fetchAwsCredentials = {
try {
    return new ProfileCredentialsProvider().getCredentials()
} catch (Exception e) {
    logger.debug('Unable to retrieve AWS credentials from profile, publishing to S3 will not be available.', e)
        return null
}
}

AWSCredentials awsCredentials =  fetchAwsCredentials()


repositories {
mavenCentral()
maven {
url 'xxxxxxxx/<Bucket-Name>/snapshots/'
credentials(AwsCredentials) {
               accessKey awsCredentials.AWSAccessKeyId
               secretKey awsCredentials.AWSSecretKey
}
}
}


publish {
dependsOn assemble
}


publishing {
publications {
    maven(MavenPublication) {
        groupId this.properties['group']
        artifactId this.properties['mavenArtifactId']
        from components.java
    }
}
repositories {
    maven {
        name 'repo'
        credentials(AwsCredentials) {

              accessKey awsCredentials.AWSAccessKeyId
              secretKey awsCredentials.AWSSecretKey

        }
        if (project.version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT')) {
            url "xxxxxxxx/<Bucket-Name>/snapshots/"
        } else {
            url "xxxxxxxx/<Bucket-Name>/releases/"
        }
    }


}

}
```

But I am getting below error

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Credentials must be an instance of: org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.PasswordCredentials
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.transport.RepositoryTransportFactory.convertPasswordCredentials(RepositoryTransportFactory.java:87)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.transport.RepositoryTransportFactory.access$100(RepositoryTransportFactory.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.transport.RepositoryTransportFactory$DefaultResourceConnectorSpecification.getCredentials(RepositoryTransportFactory.java:136)
    at org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpConnectorFactory.createResourceConnector(HttpConnectorFactory.java:36)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.transport.RepositoryTransportFactory.createTransport(RepositoryTransportFactory.java:101)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.transport.RepositoryTransportFactory.createTransport(RepositoryTransportFactory.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.getTransport(DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.java:122)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.createResolver(DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.createRealResolver(DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.createResolver(DefaultMavenArtifactRepository.java:91)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ResolveIvyFactory.create(ResolveIvyFactory.java:92)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultDependencyResolver$1.execute(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:92)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultDependencyResolver$1.execute(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:137)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:61)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultIvyContextManager.withIvy(DefaultIvyContextManager.java:39)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.DefaultDependencyResolver.resolve(DefaultDependencyResolver.java:90)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver$1.run(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:42)
    at org.gradle.internal.Factories$1.create(Factories.java:22)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:192)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheAccess.useCache(DefaultCacheAccess.java:175)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.useCache(DefaultPersistentDirectoryStore.java:106)
    at org.gradle.cache.internal.DefaultCacheFactory$ReferenceTrackingCache.useCache(DefaultCacheFactory.java:187)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.DefaultCacheLockingManager.useCache(DefaultCacheLockingManager.java:64)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(CacheLockingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:40)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.resolve(SelfResolvingDependencyResolver.java:45)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ShortcircuitEmptyConfigsArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(ShortcircuitEmptyConfigsArtifactDependencyResolver.java:58)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.resolve(ErrorHandlingArtifactDependencyResolver.java:47)
    ... 81 more

Looks like it failing because of incorrect condition added in gradle jar-:

https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/resources-http/src/main/java/org/gradle/internal/resource/transport/http/HttpClientConfigurer.java

Any Clue ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem you are facing is for wrong S3 Url pattern.

There are two interfaces extends from base `Credentials` interface.

- AwsCredentials
- PasswordCredentials

When you used `url 'xxxxxxxx/<Bucket-Name>/snapshots/'`, it detects the maven repo as just normal url. That is why it was asking for `PasswordCredentials`.

You should use `s3://<bucket-name>.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`. Here it will ask for `AwsCredentials`.

IMHO you should use two different buckets for releases and snapshots.

```
repositories {
    maven {
        name 'repo'
        credentials(AwsCredentials) {
            accessKey awsCredentials.AWSAccessKeyId
            secretKey awsCredentials.AWSSecretKey
        }
        if (project.version.endsWith('-SNAPSHOT')) {
            url "s3://<bucket-name>-snapshots.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
        } else {
            url "s3://<bucket-name>-releases.s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com"
        }
    }
}
```